# Vector valued linear differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

Let $I$ be an interval in$\mathbb{R}$ and suppose.
$$\bf \dot{x(t)} =A(t)x(t),t\in I\hspace{1cm}(\star)$$
is a linear first order differential equation with $A$ an $n\times n$matrix of continuous functions on an $I$. Suppose $\bf y_1(t), . . . ,y_n(t)$ are $n$ solutions of this differential equation on $I$.  Let $W=W(\bf y_1, . . . ,y_n) $ $:I\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be the function given by $W(t) = \det [\bf y_1(t), . . . ,y_n(t)],(t∈I)$ ,where $[\bf y_1(t), . . . ,y_n(t)]$ is regarded an $n\times n$ matrix whose $i^{th}$ column is $\bf y_i(t)$ $,i= 1, . . . , n.$ We need to show that either $W$ is identically zero on $I$ or it is nowhere vanishing on $I$.

My idea as below:
$[\bf y_1(t), . . . ,y_n(t)]$ are solution of $(\star) $ and $V:=\{x(t):\, (\star) \}$ is clearly $n$ dimensional $\mathbb{R}-$vector space.
Note that, $\bf y_i(t)$ $\in V,i= 1, . . . , n.$
Now if $[\bf y_1(t), . . . ,y_n(t)]$ form a basis ( linearly independent is enough here)then results directly follows as in a $n\times n$ matrix, $\det$ is non zero iff all columns of it are linearly independent.

Is this a correct strategy?
Any helpful comments or answer are welcome and thank for that.

Comment: Your idea is correct. But you need to show that if they are independent at $t=0$, they remain independent for all $t$, and if they are dependent at $t=0$ the same is true at any $t$. Hint: use uniqueness.

Comment: I already proved the uniqueness and implicitly assumed here. Thank you for your point.

Comment: Do you know that $W$ is the inital letter of "Wronskian", with an abundant litterature on it ?